# How do I loop through tags in a jekyll post?

Tags: jekyll

Within my post, I have three tags in my front matter, I am trying to loop through these tags but it just puts all three of them mashed together in one string.

I am using this:

```
<tr>
{% for tag in post.tags %}
<td>{{ post.tag }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

I'd like an out of the box solution instead of relying on plugins but I am hosting my own so I am able to use them if I have to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are referencing `page.tags` instead of just `tag` in your loop. Use the following:

```
<tr>
{% for tag in page.tags %}
<td>{{ tag }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

Read more in the [documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables).

Comment: ok, I'm marking this one as correct cause it was part of the answer and put me back to looking over syntax and not for different calls. But you need to read my own answer as well to get a full picture and see if that is what was causing your own problem. Thanks rudolph9!

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I finally figured it out. This is not really covered in the documentation very well but makes ALL the difference. Jekyll supports **BOTH** `tag: x, y, z` **AND** `tags: x, y, z` - the *s* is very important. That changes whether or not jekyll will interpret multiple values or a single - the same problem can be found with `category -> categories` in the front matter.

I likely missed it because I was using:

```
tag:
- x
- y
- z
```

Which is also supported but would not return string literal of "x, y, z" which might have ben a give away. Anyways, Thanks to rudolph9 for at least validating that my general direction was correct and for the syntax catch. I'm marking his as the right answer (cause I'm a nice guy) but you need to read this one as well to get the full learning McMeal.